# Neo4j Looking to return senders sending multiple unique attachments to recipient(s)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working with inbound email data with neo4j.  I am looking to return `senders sending multiple unique attachments to recipient or recipients`.

I have tried the following but this seems to return single and multiple distinct attachments instead of only >=2 attachments

```
MATCH path = (s:Sender)-[]->(a:Attachment)-[]->(r:Recipient)
WITH s, COLLECT(path) as paths
WHERE SIZE(paths) > 2
return distinct paths
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should return only those paths involving senders that have sent multiple attachments:

```
MATCH path = (s:Sender)-->(a:Attachment)-->(:Recipient)
WITH s, COUNT(DISTINCT a) AS cnt, COLLECT(path) AS paths
WHERE cnt >= 2
return paths
```

The trick is to count *distinct* attachments per sender.

Comment: nice @cybersam - i wasn't seeing it